# coldfusion xmltransform displays as one big block

Tags: xml, xslt, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm playing around with XML and XSL.  I have an XMLfile that looks somewhat like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="/_xslt/xslt_terms.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
    <terms>
       <term><p>Use of Website</p>
           <term>
                <term><p>wording here</p></term>
                <term><p>more words!</p></term>
           </term>
        <term><p>serious words</p></term>
    </terms>
```

and an XSL file that looks like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

<xsl:template match="term">
    <xsl:number level="multiple" format="1. "/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output should display like

```
 1. Use of Website
    1.1. 
        1.1.1. wording here
        1.1.2. more words

    1.2. serious words
```

but when i run

```
<cfoutput>
     <cffile action="read" 
             file="#application.sPath#_xslt/xslt_terms.xsl" 
             variable="variables.xmltrans">
     <cfset variables.xmldoc = XmlParse("#application.sPath#_templates/_ajax/_terms/xml_terms.xml")>
     #XMLTransform(variables.xmldoc, variables.xmltrans)#
</cfoutput>
```

i get a giant block of text with no line breaks.  so it looks like:

```
 1. Use of Website 1.1. 1.1.1. wording here 1.1.2. more words 1.2. serious words
```

As i say, this is the first time i'm playing around with XML and XSL since.. a long time, so it's likely i've missed something

EDIT

I found some code to help which nearly does the job.  I've changed my xml to remove all `<p>` tags, and i've changed my xsl file to read:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="term">
    <p>
        <xsl:number format="1." level="multiple"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

This nearly does it, but i'm losing the indentation, is there anything i can do to make it indented like above?

Comment: Please show more details of the XSLT, in particular the `xsl:output method`. Also tell us which HTTP `Content-Type` header you send with your server-side code. Are you sending `text/plain` or `text/html`?

Comment: ahhh the code for the XSL is the entire code... so i'm obviously missing something.  i'll look at the `xsl:output` now.  `content-type` is: `text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: If the content type is text/html then you need to make sure the XSLT creates HTML and not plain text as it currently does, otherwise the browser will render your lines of text as HTML and with HTML white space is collapsed into blanks and that way you simply get a line of text. So change the content type to text/plain or make sure the XSLT creates HTML elements structuring the output.

Comment: I can't output the whole page as text/plain since it's embedded within a html page.. so i should use `<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>` within the xsl... though doing that still leaves me with a big block of text.

Comment: @MartinHonnen see my new code.  nearly there.

Comment: As a sort of hack you could change the `<p><xsl:number format="1." level="multiple"/><xsl:apply-templates/></p>` to `<pre><xsl:number format="1." level="multiple"/><xsl:apply-templates/></pre>`. But I would consider to let the XSLT create a HTML ordered list instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make sure that the complete HTML document your XSLT output is injected in can include some CSS then I would suggest to create a HTML ordered, nested list where the numbers are done with CSS:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5.0"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>list test</title>
                <style>
                    ol.nested  { counter-reset: section; list-style-type: none; }
                    ol.nested li { counter-increment: section; }
                    ol.nested li:before { content: counters(section, ".") ". "; }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="terms[term]">
        <ol class="nested">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ol>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="term">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::term)]"/>
            <xsl:if test="term">
                <ol class="nested">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="term"/>
                </ol>
            </xsl:if>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the input XML being

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sheet.xsl"?>
<terms>
    <term><p>Use of Website</p>
        <term>
            <term><p>wording here</p></term>
            <term><p>more words!</p></term>
        </term>
        <term><p>serious words</p></term>
    </term>
</terms>
```

modern browsers will render that as a nested listed with the counting you want.

If you want to create the numbers with XSLT then I would still create a HTML list as the HTML needs to be structured:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5.0"/>

    <xsl:template match="terms[term]">
        <ol style="list-style-type: none;">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ol>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="term">
        <li><xsl:number level="multiple" format="1. "/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::term)]"/>
            <xsl:if test="term">
                <ol style="list-style-type: none;">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="term"/>
                </ol>
            </xsl:if>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now when applied to the input

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sheet.xsl"?>
<terms>
    <term><p>Use of Website</p>
        <term>
            <term><p>wording here</p></term>
            <term><p>more words!</p></term>
        </term>
        <term><p>serious words</p></term>
    </term>
</terms>
```

you get the numbering you want.

Comment: I already had this working with OL and CSS, I was trying out XML and XSL so that older browsers would also render it nicely.  If there isn't an easy solution I might stick with the OL and CSS option.

Comment: @Jarede, I have added a sample with XSLT that uses `xsl:number`.